# Get the value of a property from ModelMetadata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I'm attempting to implement a custom `ModelBinder` overloading the following creation method to allow me to bind to abstract classes.

```
protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                      ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
                                      Type modelType){

  const string WidgetId = "WidgetId";
  ValueProviderResult widgetIdResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
                                                     .GetValue(WidgetId);

  if (widgetIdResult == null)
  {
    throw new Exception("Widget id for abstract class not specified.");
  }

  IWidget widget = 
  (IWidget)ContentHelper.GetNodeById(int.Parse(widgetIdResult.AttemptedValue));
                    
  IRenderWidget instance = 
                widget.BuildViewModel(ConverterHelper.Instance.UmbracoHelper);

  bindingContext.ModelMetadata = 
  ModelMetadataProviders.Current
                        .GetMetadataForType(() => instance, instance.GetType());
  return instance;
}
```

With the code above I am able to successfully create an instance of my class which inherit my abstract type.

What I cannot then do is populate the values from the form against the model which has a property **Form** Once I get to my ActionResult the form values are empty.

```
public ActionResult SubmitForm(RenderModel model,
[ModelBinder(typeof(FormWidgetModelBinder))]RenderFormBase form)
```

Using TryUpdate

```
this.TryUpdateModel(form);
```

Doesn't work.

Can someone demonstrate how to bind the form values?

### Update

If I use the example linked in the comments I get the following error.

> The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter
> 'form' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
> SubmitForm(Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel,
> Site.Models.ViewModels.DocumentTypes.Widgets.RenderFormBase)' in
> 'Site.Controllers.WidgetPageController'. The dictionary contains a
> value of type
> 'Site.Models.ViewModels.DocumentTypes.Widgets.RenderContactUs', but
> the parameter requires a value of type
> 'Site.Models.ViewModels.DocumentTypes.Widgets.RenderFormBase'.
> Parameter name: parameters

Comment: Not clear what your asking or trying to do. If your model contains a property named `Content` but your not rendering a control for it, or its child properties (_I could move the value to a hidden field_) then its value will not be posted back so therefore its value cant be set

Comment: I'll update the question to expand on what I am doing.

Comment: [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx) - the section on _Abstract Model Binder_ - might help.

Comment: Yeah I had a look at that. I've updated my question with the resultant error message.